# Textmate shows files in the project folder that have been deleted

Tags: textmate

This might be a silly question, but can we prevent the displaying of old references in the project list view? I see files that were deleted but still show with an "X" icon. I wish I could attach a screenshot.

Comment: Did you work out a solution?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498033/remove-textmate-git-bundle

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590302/textmate-2-alpha-showing-references-for-deleted-files

Comment: Thanks! this works too git add -A .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, this is a git issue, and not a textmate issue.

Try this:

```
$ git commit -a -m "git comment"
$ git push origin master
```

According to the OP, this will also work:

```
$ git add -A
```

Reference:
[Textmate 2 Alpha showing references for deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590302/textmate-2-alpha-showing-references-for-deleted-files)

Comment: Thanks it's "git add -A . " but again what if you don't use git hub for other stuff? there has to be something.

Comment: I think it won't show up as an "X" if there is no external git repo.

Comment: This is totally a Textmate issue, considering Textmate is showing files that don't exist and is explicitly and intentionally interfacing with git in order to do so, to the potential detriment of usability. Just because it can be traced back to the git repo doesn't make it not a Textmate issue.