# Remove Textmate Git Bundle

Tags: git, bundle, textmate

I don't want to use the git bundle! I removed it but I still see files under
"Uncommitted Changes" and "Untracked Items"

I don't know how to clean those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page on "[RevertToDefaultBundles](http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/RevertToDefaultBundles)" does mention:

> If you have ever done a svn checkout of bundles it would most likely have been done to:

```
/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles
```

> Third party bundles installed via double-clicking or dragging to TextMate would be installed in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles
```

> Custom bundles and customizations you have done to either default bundles or third party bundles are kept in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles
```

> **After having removed all customized and/or third party bundles, either relaunch TextMate or select `Reload Bundles` from the `Bundles → Bundle Editor` menu**.
>
> In addition to removing the Bundles folder, there may also exist a Support and/or a PlugIns folder in any of the three above locations.
>   You also want to remove these, if you want to revert to factory defaults.