# Textmate 2 Alpha showing references for deleted files

Tags: textmate

I know it's an Alpha product, but I think this is a setting rather than a bug. When I delete files from with textmate file manager, the file is deleted but remains in the project with a red 'X' through it. See the image below.

I have checked on the file system and it is not there, and have also git commited and pushed the changes to my github repo.

Any ideas?

[image]

**EDIT**

Cross-posted to the Textmate mailing list. No answers so far.
http://textmate.1073791.n5.nabble.com/Textmate-2-Alpha-and-deleting-files-td26669.html

**SOLUTION**

As per danodonovan's suggestion, I looked into the git issues. Turns out **git status** showed the files up, and eventually they were commited.

This did not work:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git push origin master
```

This did work:

```
$ git commit -a -m "message"
$ git push origin master
```

I thought -a -m was synonymous for the first set of commands. In any case the problem is solved and was not a Textmate issue but rather uncommited deletions, which makes sense. Thank you to danodonovan.

Comment: This is the link I am using. Is there a more up-to-date version somewhere? http://macromates.com/download. I'm on version 2.0-alpha.9443 which seems to be one minor release back: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/releases

Comment: No - I was being daft - sorry.

Comment: No worries -- thanks for the responding to the post. I'm sure this is a feature but I cannot work out how to turn it off. It's a bit annoying: not sure why you would want to see all your deleted files.

Comment: does `$ git status` show the files? (you may need to commit the file deletion as well as other changes)

Comment: Yes $ git status shows the files, marked as deleted. I am confused as I have commited and pushed several times. The files are listed under "Changes not staged for commit"

Comment: @danodonovan - you are right. When I add with git add . these files are missed, but when I ran $ git commit -a -m "comment" and pushed to github, it removed the files. If you want to write something as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do these files show up with

```
$ git status
```

? As you've found out you'll either have to commit the removed files individually or use

```
$ git commit -a -m "comment"
```

:-)