# How can I keep deleted files from showing up in TextMate 2 file-browser sidebar?

Tags: textmate2

In Textmate 2, when you rename a file, the new filename shows up in the file-browser sidebar, but the old filename does, too, with a red X. The old filename won't go away until you commit your name change. This has been infuriating me for years. I refactor & rename a lot, and I constantly click on the wrong/deleted filenames during the refactor.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

I have tried disabling all SCM-related bundles, but that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: BTW, this is NOT a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590302/textmate-2-alpha-showing-references-for-deleted-files. I know I can get the deleted files to disappear by committing. I just don't want the deleted files to show up EVER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new [last week](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Applications/TextMate/about/Changes.md#2018-11-01-v20-rc14):

> It is possible to set `excludeSCMDeleted = true` in a `.tm_properties` file to hide the “ghost” items that appear after deleting a file on disk which is still tracked by your version control system.

Comment: Markdown mangled your link but thanks for the info! Here'e a working link: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Applications/TextMate/about/Changes.md#2018-11-01-v20-rc14 This is AWESOME. I can stop prematurely committing mid-stream refactoring jobs just to get rid of these ghost files.

Comment: For everyone scratching their heads seing `.tm_properties` – it's a file that you create in your project's dirs.

Comment: This did not work for me