# How to hide deleted files in TextMate's file browser

Tags: textmate, textmate2

If I open a folder that uses source control in TextMate, it will show deleted files with an x. How do I hide deleted files?

The solution in this answer does not work: [How can I keep deleted files from showing up in TextMate 2 file-browser sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428259/how-can-i-keep-deleted-files-from-showing-up-in-textmate-2-file-browser-sidebar)

[image]

Comment: What does ‘git status’ say? IIRC this state happens when you’ve deleted a file but haven’t removed it from git, or removed it from git but haven’t deleted the file.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath That is what the x indicates. I want the file to not show up in TextMate when I delete the file. The solution in other answers to "just commit the change" is not a solution, it's a hack.